# Bluetooth fails to function (due to internet connection)

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, bluetooth

After an update with the bluetooth driver, my computer can't send files, it can receive at certain times but eventually fail if the file is large (5 mb large), then I noticed whenever I'm connected to the internet, my bluetooth can't even detect my android phone. I uninstalled my bluetooth, replacing it with its built-in driver (the Generic something...), but still can't detect any bluetooth.

My android phone can detect my laptop, even tried pairing but it didn't work.
Also tried disabling metered connection.
Even after disconnecting to the internet, my laptop can't send or receive files at all.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the Bluetooth File Transfer Wizard through fsquirt.exe

> The Bluetooth File Transfer Wizard enables users to transfer files
>   between a computer and a Bluetooth device. For example, users can
>   transfer files between a computer and a mobile phone or a personal
>   digital assistant (PDA). The Bluetooth File Transfer Wizard can also
>   transfer files between two computers that support Bluetooth.

The default GUI that the Bluetooth File Transfer Wizard uses is implemented in the **Fsquirt.exe** file.

To initiate a file transfer simply enter Win key + R then input fsquirt in the Run dialog box.

For convenience, you can even add the fsquirt shortcut to the right click context menu as a **Send to Bluetooth devices option** like shown below:

[image]